# C# get array from dictionary with respect to other array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, dictionary

I have data like:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();    
dic.Add("1", "ABC1");    
dic.Add("2", "ABC2");    
dic.Add("3", "ABC3");    
dic.Add("4", "ABC4");    
dic.Add("5", "ABC5");    
dic.Add("6", "ABC6");  
string[] col = new string[] { "1", "4", "5" };
```

needed a result string array in the same order as col array like:

```
string[] res = new string[] { "ABC1", "ABC4", "ABC5" };
```

tried with for loop but needed in linq

```
string[] res = new string[col.Length]; // { "ABC1", "ABC4", "ABC5" };

for(int i=0;i<col.Length;i++)
{
    res[i] = dic[col[i]];
}
```

Comment: Hint: LINQ's Select and ToArray methods make this very simple.

Comment: I see a LINQ tag but no evidence that you tried to solve this with LINQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unsafe way is just to `Select` directly from dictionary:

```
var result = col.Select(c => dic[c]).ToArray();
```

But it is more recommended to check that the key is in the dictionary to avoid exception

```
var result = col.Where(c => dic.Keys.Contains(c))
                .Select(c => dic[c])
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = dic.Where(k => col.Contains(k.Key)).Select(v => v.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: string[] col = new string[] { "1", "5", "4" }; if col array is like this then result is still lke { "ABC1", "ABC4", "ABC5" }; but i want { "ABC1", "ABC5", "ABC4" };

Comment: Right. Then @GiladGreen's answer should do it.